# PowerShell 3.0 Script for adding secondary IP address

Tags: powershell-3.0

Can any one tell me that what is the PowerShell 3.0 Script for adding secondary IP address ?

'get-netipaddress' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet. Is there any alternate command for adding secondary Ip addresss as I can not use 'get-netipaddress'command.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On which Windows version are you running your powershell script?

Comment: Windows 2008 server

Comment: got the resolution